# Search in multiple column with at least 2 words in keyword

Tags: mysql

I have a table which store some datas. This is my table structure.

| Course | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Wolden | New York |
| Sertigo | Seatlle |
| Monad | Chicago |
| Donner | Texas |

I want to search from that table for example with this keyword `Sertigo Seattle` and it will return row number two as a result.

I have this query but doesn't work.

`SELECT * FROM courses_data a WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', a.Courses, a.Location) LIKE '%Sertigo Seattle%'`

Maybe anyone knows how to make query to achieve my needs?

Comment: (1) `Seattle` is NOT the same as `Seatlle` (2) `Courses` is NOT the same as `Course`. Otherwise CONCAT_WS (I mean your select query) should work if there is no special/space characters in your db table fields

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search against the course and location then use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM courses_data
WHERE Course = 'Sertigo' AND Location = 'Seattle';
```

Comment: I can't split what is the keyword will be use to filter the query because user will input it dynamicaly via search form.

Answer (score 0):

Efficient searching is usually implemented by preparing the search string before running the actual search:

You split the search string "Sertigo Seattle" into two *words*: "Sertigo" and "Seattle". You *trim* those words (remove enclosing white space characters). You might also want to *normalize* the words, perhaps convert them to all lower case to implement a case insentive search.

Then you run a search for the discrete words:

```
SELECT *
  FROM courses_data
    WHERE 
      (Course = 'Sertigo' AND Location = 'Seattle')
    OR
      (Course = 'Seattle' AND Location = 'Sertigo');
```

Of course that query is created using a prepared statement and parameter binding, using the extracted and trimmed *words* as dynamic parameters.

This is is much more efficient than using wildcard based search with the `LIKE` operator. Because the database engine can make use of the indexes you (hopefully) created for that table. You can check that by using `EXPLAIN` feature MySQL offers.

Also it does make sense to measure performance: run different search approaches in a loop, say 1000 times, and take the required time. You will get a clear and meaningful example. Also monitoring CPU and memory usage in such a test is of interest.

Comment: I can't split what is the keyword will be use to filter the query because user will input it dynamicaly via search form.

Comment: And why can't you split that? Of course the search string is dynamic. Otherwise you could simply implement a static query. An efficient search is _always_ implemented based on words, never on long, complex strings. Because it is impossible use a helpful index without splitting up search string and topics.